# Cannot connect to AWS RDS mariadb instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

We have a working AWS RDS instance. But I cannot connect to this database with its proper credentials. The security group has the private ip range from where I'm trying to access.

tracert  --> This command returns 'Request timed out' after a 3 hops.

What am I missing?

Note : There are people who can connect to the database already. Somewhere there IP is whitelisted and mine is not?

Comment: `telnet instance_endpoint 3306` returns `Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed`

Comment: If other people can connect but you cannot, then the problem most probably is related to your computer. Try connecting from a different network (eg home vs office), or at least from the same network as the people for whom it works. Failing that, please edit your question to provide more details. For example, how are you connecting (from the Internet? via a Direct Connect connection?) and how you are connecting to a Private IP address. Also, how are you referring to the database -- is it via DNS Name or IP address? You'll need to give us more information to be able to assist.

Comment: Hi, I've tried connecting the db from office as well as home network. It works for few people in office. But they have been using it for long. I'm connecting to the endpoint name of the database : *.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
While connecting from Heidisql i'm getting 10060 error code.

Answer (score 1):

From AWS RSD click on "VPC security groups" and change the source of the inbound traffice of the associated EC2 to anywhere. Obviously the issue was the security group Source IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if the ip address of the machines that can successfully connect and that of your machine lie within the same CIDR configured in the security group ? Also confirm if your local machine has some firewall preventing you from outbound traffic in the specified port ?

Comment: yes both private IPs are covered by the ip range present in the inbound rule of the security group.